# Strip spaces after single capital letters with sed

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I am writing a bash script to automatically generate some other files, and I have to format some strings a certain way. Specifically, the last problem I'm having is formatting a string that has individual capital letters and a word that starts with a capital letter. For example:

`O S D Settings` needs to become `OSD Settings`

I have a sed command that strips the first space, but it also deletes the "D" (i.e. `O S D Settings` -> `OS Settings`). This command is:

```
O S D Settings | sed 's/ \([A-Z]\)* \(A-Za-z]*\)/\1/g'
```

Does anyone know how to delete the spaces in between individual capital letters without losing any letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using sed with pipes to get a statement that is easy for me to understand:

```
echo O S D Settings | sed 's/\([A-Z][^ ]\)/_\1/g' | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/_/ /g'
```

All this does is replaces the spaces I don't want with the underscore and then deletes them. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 4):

This takes care of names like `A B Chadwick` and `A B C D'Souza`

Text such as `A B cde` and `A B CDE` are not modified.

It uses two temporary null characters `\x00` to mark changes (per name) as it progress through a line, removing spaces.

`:N` and `:S` are *branch-to* labels (any name will do)
`t` and `b` are branching instructions.
`t` branches upon a successful replacemnt in the previous `s/../../` command.
`b` branches unconditionally.

```
sed -r ":N                                                # loop per name
         /(\<[A-Z]\> )+[A-Z][a-z']/{                      # line needs action
             s/((\<[A-Z]\> )+)([A-Z][a-z'])/\x00\1\x00\3/ # add \x00 markers
            :S                                            # loop per space
             s/(\x00[A-Z]+) (\<[A-Z]\>)/\1\2/             # delete a space
             t S                                          # any more spaces? 
             b N                                          # any more names?
         }; s/\x00//g"                                    # remove \x00
```

Answer (score 3):

It's tricky with `sed`, but if `perl` is okay you can do it this way

```
echo O S D Settings | perl -p -e 's/(\b[A-Z]) (?=.([^\w]|$))/$1/g'
```

This is hard in `sed` because it does not support look-ahead assertions.

Tests:

```
echo O S D | perl -p -e 's/(\b[A-Z]) (?=.([^\w]|$))/$1/g'
echo O S D Settings | perl -p -e 's/(\b[A-Z]) (?=.([^\w]|$))/$1/g'
echo O S D. | perl -p -e 's/(\b[A-Z]) (?=.([^\w]|$))/$1/g'
echo One O DDE T. S Asdf Q R Tee | perl -p -e 's/(\b[A-Z]) (?=.([^\w]|$))/$1/g'
echo O S D\  | perl -p -e 's/([A-Z]) (?=.([^\w]|$))/$1/g'
```

If you want a sloppy solution with `sed`, try

```
echo O S D Settings | sed -e 's/ \([A-Z]\) \([A-Z] \)/\1\2/g'
```

Which works for your sample, but will fail for other cases.

Tests:

```
echo O S D | sed -e 's/ \([A-Z]\) \([A-Z] \)/\1\2/g'
echo O S D Settings | sed -e 's/ \([A-Z]\) \([A-Z] \)/\1\2/g'
echo O S D. | sed -e 's/ \([A-Z]\) \([A-Z] \)/\1\2/g'
echo One O DDE T. S Asdf Q R Tee | sed -e 's/ \([A-Z]\) \([A-Z] \)/\1\2/g'
echo O S D\  | sed -e 's/ \([A-Z]\) \([A-Z] \)/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: Can't use perl. But thanks for the thorough answer anyway

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo "O S D Settings and B T W and A B C D'Souza too F Y I" |
sed ':a;s/\(\<[[:upper:]]\>\) \(\<[[:upper:]]\>\([^'\'']\|$\)\)/\1\n\2/g;ta;s/\n//g'
OSD Settings and BTW and ABC D'Souza too FYI
```

Explanation:

Use a character that does not exist in the original string to replace the spaces you want deleting, then delete that chosen character throughout the string. `\n` is a good candidate as it cannot exist normally because it is used by sed as line delimiter.

Comment: I had already found my answer before seeing yours and mine is easier for me to understand. Thanks anyway